# RegEx to accept only numbers between 0-9

Tags: c#, regex

I'm fairly new to using regex and I've got a problem with the results of this one.

Regex @"^0[0-9]{9,10}$" is accepting spaces between the digits. How to I stop this as I only want digits between 0-9 to be acceptable characters.

The valid result should start with zero and have either 9 or 10 digits (no spaces or any other character is permissible).

All help appreciated.

Here's my code

```
Regex telephoneExp = new Regex(@"^0[0-9]{9,10}$");
if (telephoneExp.Match(txtTelephoneNumber.Text).Success==false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The telephone number is not valid, it must only contain digits (0-9) and be either 10 or 11 digits in length.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `0[0-9]{9,10}` should work? but if you accept phone numbers, you should accept lots of formats, and there are lots of formats. You can strip the non digit characters out after.

Comment: Your regex is correct. Your problem lies somewhere else

Comment: This code works, which means that your problem lies elsewhere, which means you haven't given us enough information to know that however we solved your problem will actually work for others in the future who may have had the same error you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
^0\d{9,10}$
```

Matches `0`, then 9 to 10 digits.

You could also use `Regex.IsMatch` instead:

```
Regex telephoneExp = new Regex(@"^0\d{9,10}$");
if (!telephoneExp.IsMatch(txtTelephoneNumber.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The telephone number is not valid, it must only contain digits (0-9) and be either 10 or 11 digits in length.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is the same as `@"^0[0-9]{9,10}$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hadn't finished my answer, sorry

Comment: Still, the code is equivalent

Comment: @RedLaser thanks for the help, it was not the format of the Regex that was the issue, it was how I was using the match. Your suggestion of using the IsMatch method has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this to check if it's only a number:

```
^\d*$
```

UPDATE:

```
(^0\d{8,9})$
```

Checks if 9 or 10 digits starting with leading 0

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Comment: Would even be wrong if it would answer the question, as it does match less than 9 and more than 10 numbers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, you can use LINQ:

```
var text = txtTelephoneNumber.Text;
bool valid = false;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    valid = text.First() == '0' &&
            9 <= text.Count() && text.Count() <= 10 &&
            text.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c));
}

if (!valid)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but remove empty chars using Trim() function 100% it will working fine,

```
Regex telephoneExp = new Regex(@"^0[0-9]{9,10}$");
if (telephoneExp.Match(txtTelephoneNumber.Text.Trim()).Success==false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The telephone number is not valid, it must only contain digits (0-9) and be either 10 or 11 digits in length.");
    return false;
}
```